# React Native: How to select previous Text Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have defined code as to focus on next `TextInput` field

```
 <View>
     <TextInput
         ref="1"
         maxLength = {1}
         keyboardType={"numeric"}
         onChangeText={(pC1) => this.focusNextField('2',pC1)}
         value={this.state.pC1}
     />
     <TextInput
         ref="2"
         maxLength = {1}
         keyboardType={"numeric"}
         onChangeText={(pC2) => this.focusNextField('3',pC2)}
         value={this.state.pC2}
     />
     <TextInput
          ref="3"
          maxLength = {1}
          keyboardType={"numeric"}
          onChangeText={(pC3) => this.focusNextField('',pC3)}
          value={this.state.pC3}
      /> 
  </View>
```

Following are the functions written for text input cursor shifting in
forward direction. But how to make the implementation in reverse
order.That is, by pressing backspace(keypad)

```
  focusNextField(nextField,pinCode) {
      if(nextField=="2"){
        if(pinCode!=''){
          this.state.pC1=pinCode; // Set value for PC1
          this.refs[nextField].focus();//Goes to TextInput whose ref == 2
        }else{
          this.state.pC1='';
          nextField="1";
          this.refs[nextField].focus();
        }
      }else if(nextField=="3"){
        if(pinCode!=''){
          this.state.pC2=pinCode; // Set value for PC2
          this.refs[nextField].focus();//Goes to TextInput whose ref == 3
        }else{
          this.state.pC2='';
          nextField="2";
          this.refs[nextField].focus();
        }
      }else if(nextField==""){
        if(pinCode!=''){
          this.state.pC3=pinCode; // Set value for PC3
        }else{
          this.state.pC3='';
          nextField="3";
          this.refs[nextField].focus();
        }
      }
    this.forceUpdate(); //Update the Component
  }
```

In the above code I am able to move forward from one `TextInput` to another.
My question is: how can I focus on the previous `TextInput` if I remove
`TextInput` data?

Comment: If backspace will be used for moving to another TextInput, then how would a user erase his text ?

Comment: @Fawaz Its fine if it erase his text do have solution for it

Comment: You can use onKeyPress event but its only available for ios https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onkeypress

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the behavior you are looking for is : If input not empty, focus on next if there is any, if input is empty, focus on previous if there is any. I suggest that you reduce the complexity of your function by declaring a mapping as follows :

```
focusNextField (currentField, pinCode) {
    const mapping = {
        '1': {
            variable: 'pC1',
            next: '2'
        },
        '2': {
            variable: 'pC2',
            prev: '1',
            next: '3'
        },
        '3': {
            variable: 'pC3',
            prev: '2'
        },
    };
    this.state[mapping[currentField].variable] = pinCode || '';
    if (pinCode) {
        if (mapping[currentField].next) {
            this.refs[mapping[currentField].next].focus();
        }
    } else {
        if (mapping[currentField].prev) {
            this.refs[mapping[currentField].prev].focus();
        }
    }

    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

The only change you need to do in your markup is sending the current field to the method instead of the next field.

Comment: Thanks for reply but mentioned solution did not work

Comment: it was unable to focus on the previous TextInput

Comment: Were you on 3 or on 2 when you wanted to focus on the previous ?

Comment: from both 2 and 3 i am unable to focus on the previous

Comment: Can you use `console.log` or `debugger` in the `else` statement to make sure that `mapping[currentField].prev` exists and that `this.refs[mapping[currentField].prev]` is the currect field to focus on ?